# Custom error message from entity class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation

How can I create a custom message for the errors that accour in the field annotation?

```
@Size(max = 10)
```

or

```
@Column(name = "NAME"  , length = 10)
```

Now I see a message

> CustomerDetailsForm:customerName: Validation Error: Length is greater than allowable maximum of ''10'' .

How can I change this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `message` attribute of the bean validation annotation.

```
@Size(max=10, message="May not be more than 10 characters.")
```

To internationalize it, supply `ValidationMessages.properties` bundle files in the desired locales and use the `{}` to specify the bundle key, e.g:

```
@Size(max=10, message="{validation.max_size}")
```

Alternatively, you can also just use `maxlength` on the `<h:inputText>` field so that the enduser already won't be able to enter too much characters.

```
<h:inputText ... maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: thank's! I want to internationalize it like you said.. what do you mean with ValidationMessages.properties bundle files? do I need to create ValidationMessages.properties?

Comment: do i need to define  ValidationMessages.properties inside something? and when i call it's message it should be "{validation.max_size}" ? thank's again.

Comment: Just put the files in the root of the classpath. The properties can be just `validation.max_size = May not be more than 10 characters.` The key and value is fully free to your choice. The `{}` just indicate that the message should be looked up from the bundle by the specified key.

Comment: 'Just put the files in the root of the classpath' - you mean the ValidationMessages.properties file right? are there any more files that should be added? I will try it now, thank's!

Comment: One file per locale. E.g. `ValidaitonMessages_en.properties`, `ValidationMessages_de.properties`, etc. See the `ResourceBundle` javadoc. It's not different from all other "usual" resource bundle approaches. If you don't need localized messages or want a default locale, you  can also just supply alone `ValidationMessages.properties`.

Comment: I managed to see the message when i write it (not from the properties file), but i had to remove my `length=10` from the `@Column`, is there a reason that i don't see the message when i have the extVal `length` validation?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use ExtVal. You also didn't told that you was using it.

Comment: o.k..thank's any way. do you know if it's possible to show my custom message without defining it inside the annotation (like - `message="{validation.max_size}"` ), so it will be shown for every field that has the `@size` attribute?

Comment: So you basically want to override the default message? The key would then be `javax.validation.constraints.Size.message` where `Size` part is the annotation name. I'm however not sure how that interferes with ExtVal. The default message which you have there is actually the default message of JSF's own `<f:validateLength>` tag. Perhaps ExtVal is grabbing it from over there. You'd instead need to  register the message bundle as `<message-bundle>` in `faces-config.xml` with exact key as specified in chapter 2.5.2.4 of JSF2 specification, which is `javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM`.

Comment: thank's again.. I tries adding the `Messages.properties` file in my classpath, and to add what you worte above - but i get this message now: `java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Messages, locale en_US` , any idea how to fix this?

Comment: That exception is telling that it's not in the classpath at all.

Comment: Can I create a custom properties file e.g: `custom_messages.properties` inside one of my application packages and set it's location in `web.xml` to be found whenever it is beening used by the defualt bean validator? thank's.

Comment: also, is it possible to combine between the `ValidaitonMessages.properties` and the `messages.properties` file that I've defined in `<message-bundle>` inside `faces-cconfig` (for ExtVal validation). I want the error messages to be combined in one file (Exval and Bean validation together).. is this possible?